# MongoDB : modify date field from Unix to date Object

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a collection full of hundreds of documents , with 'date' field in unix format ... like " 1432817993 "

How can i modify the date field to Date object instead of unix format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the unix timestamp field, use the [**`forEach()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) method of the collection's find() cursor to iterate over the documents in the collection and change the field to an ISODate object:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function (doc) {
    doc.date = new ISODate(doc.date * 1000);  
    db.collection.save(doc);
})
```

Comment: var posts = Posts.find({}).fetch()

        _.each(posts, function (post) {

            Posts.update({}, {
                $set: {
                    date: moment(post.date).toDate()
                }
            }, {
                multi: true
            }, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('date converted');
                }
            });
        })

Answer (score 1):

```
    var posts = Posts.find({}).fetch()

    _.each(posts, function (post) {

        Posts.update({}, {
            $set: {
                date: moment(post.date).toDate()
            }
        }, {
            multi: true
        }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('date converted');
            }
        });
    })
```